# How to use composer v1 on Symfony Cloud Project

Tags: php, symfony

I want to relaunch the project I had some time ago hosted on Symfony Cloud.
During deploy process there is an error:

```
      Executing build hook...
        W: + curl -s https://get.symfony.com/cloud/configurator
        W: + bash
        W: + mkdir -p /app/.global/bin/
        W: + cd /mnt/cache/app
        W: + wget -nv -N https://get.symfony.com/cloud/stable/tools.tar.bz2
        W: + tar -C /app/.global/bin/ -jxpf /mnt/cache/app/tools.tar.bz2
        W: + ln /app/.global/bin/symfony /app/.global/bin/scenv
(....)
        W: + symfony composer install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --apcu-autoloader --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts --no-progress --no-ansi --no-interaction
        W: Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
        W: Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
        W: Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
        W: 
        W:   Problem 1
        W:     - Root composer.json requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0, found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
        W:   Problem 2
        W:     - symfony/flex is locked to version v1.6.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
        W:     - symfony/flex v1.6.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
        W: 
        W: You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.
        W: unable to run /app/.global/bin/composer2 install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --apcu-autoloader --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts --no-progress --no-ansi --no-interaction: exit status 2
      
      E: Error building project: Step failed with status code 1.

    E: Error: Unable to build application, aborting.
```

My project all time worked with composer v1, but it looks like there was a change on symfony cloud ecosystem that  composer v2 is a default version now. How can I set the composer v1 for my Symfony Cloud project? Is it possible without making changes to my application code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your .symfony.cloud.yaml?

According with this post from Fabien Potencier : [link](https://symfony.com/blog/composer-2-support-in-symfony-cli-and-symfonycloud?utm_source=Symfony%20Blog%20Feed&utm_medium=feed)

> On SymfonyCloud, where composer install is ran by default, we are now using Composer version 1 or version 2 depending on the composer.lock of your project. SymfonyCloud provides Composer binaries for both versions (named composer and composer2) and uses symfony composer to automatically make the version choice. Feel free to test Composer 2 in a branch.

Normally if you don't use composer update with composer2, you don't have a composer2 used into Symfony Cloud.